# Are normal coordinates a unique property of the Levi-Civita connection?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, principal-bundles

It is a well known fact that given a Riemannian manifold $M$, then for all $x\in M$, there exists a local orthonormal frame $\{e_i\}$ on an open neighborhood of $x$ such that:

$$(\nabla e_i)(x)=0$$
for all $i$.

Suppose $E\rightarrow M$ is a vector bundle over $M$, and $\nabla$ is a covariant derivative on $E$. Does the same statement hold?

I think the answer is yes, but I am not quite sure how to prove it. Perhaps one could write the covariant derivative as connection one form on the bundle of linear frames of $E$, and then make a parallel transport argument, but I can't quite see where to really start. Perhaps I am wrong though, and the answer is no. If so, how can I construct a counter example?

Comment: Try this: Choose an arbitrary frame on a neighborhood of $x$, and show that you can change frame to make the connection 1-forms vanish *at* $x$.

Comment: @TedShifrin How do I do that? I have been playing around with it for a second, but it seems that I would need a matrix $A^i_j$ that changes frame $e_i\mapsto f_i$ that satisfies at a singular point $\partial_\mu A^i_j+A^i_k\omega^k_{\mu j}=0$. I don't really see what to do with this

Comment: Forgetting about indices, you want to solve for $A$ so that *at* $x$ you have $dA = -A\omega$. You may as well assume you’re in $\Bbb R^n$ and $x=0$. You can take $A=I$ at $0$, for example.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I almost see what you are saying, but I'm struggling to see how I get $dA=\omega$ at $x=0$. Do I just define $A:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow GL(V)$ to be $A=I-x^\mu \omega_{\mu}$?

Comment: I don’t know what that means.

Comment: Remember that if we take $\omega(0)$, it is a matrix of $1$-forms.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am trying to find an $A$, which satisfies $dA=-A\omega$ at $x=0$ per your comment. Let $\omega=\omega_\mu dx^\mu$,  then with $A=I-x^\mu\omega_{\mu}(0)$, is map which for a small enough open neighborhood of the $0$ has image in $GL(V)$. Taking the exterior derivative gives $dA=-\omega_\mu(0)dx^\mu$ so at $x=0$ the equation is satisfies since $A=I$ at $0$. Is this not what you meant?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry to bother you, but is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, looks just fine. You should write an answer.

Comment: Done, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually easy, per Ted Shiffrin's comment, and I believe works in particular for metric connections as well. Just restrict the following answer to the bundle of orthonormal frames for your vector bundle and everything should as earlier.

Let $e_i$ be a local frame on $E_U$, and $x\in M$ be a point. Suppose that
$f_i$ is any other local frame related to $e_i$ by a matrix of functions $A\in GL(V)$:

$f_i=A^j_ie_j$.

If, in the original local frame we have:

$$\nabla e_i = \omega_i^je_j$$

for the connection one form $\omega$, then we see that by Leibniz property of covariant derivatives:

$$\nabla f_i= (dA_i^je_j+A^j_k \omega^k_i)e_j$$

It follows that for this to be zero at a point we need:

$$(dA)_x=-(A\omega)_x$$

Choose a coordinate chart $\phi$, shrinking $U$ if necessary, such that $\phi(x)=0\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and let $x^\mu$ be the coordinates for this chart. Let $\omega_\mu=\omega(\partial_\mu)\in\mathfrak{gl}(V)$. Shrink $U$ further such that the function:

$$A=I-x^\mu \omega_\mu(0)$$

lies in $GL(V)$. Then we see that:

$$dA=-\omega(0)$$

It follows that $A$ takes $e_i$ to a frame which is then parallel at the point the $x\in M$, as desired.